# Can Boruto really use water style?

Tags: boruto

So far in the anime, Boruto doesn't seem to have actually used water style on his own. The only times he's done it has been with the ninja tool from that scientist dude.

Even though the [Wikia](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki) stated that Boruto's nature types include Water Release, but when I think about it, he got wind from Naruto and probably inherited lightning from Minato (maybe a dormant trait), so the water style doesn't add up.

To rephrase the question in a less arguable way, does Boruto actually have water nature type?

Comment: As far as I have seen in the anime and manga, he has wind and lightning style which i think he got from his father and mother respectively. He has no water style justu. He did use one in the chunin exam but that was from the scientific ninja tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, he can. In the manga, Chapter 16,"Vessel", Boruto is having a match against Naruto and uses Water Release: Billowing Wave and mixes it with Lightning Style. The wiki probably just updates stuff according to the manga as well. Although he might just not use Water Style as much as Wind or Lightning.

Answer (score 1):

To use a jutsu of some nature you don't necessarily need to possess that chakra nature. to do some advanced jutsus you may need that chakra nature. For example, during the Fourth Great Shinobi War, everyone used Earth style to make mud walls just by making the right hand-signs. But Boruto's natural affinity is towards Wind style since he got it from Naruto.